# OData count for pagination, filtering and searching

Tags: json, pagination, odata

In conjunction with `$top` and `$skip`, there is the `@odata.count` annotation (see also http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/os/odata-json-format-v4.0-os.html#_Toc372793054).

I am not sure how this behaves with the mentioned query options. Would count return the count "behind", i.e. the count of the original collection, without top and skip applied?

What's the matter with `$filter` and `$search` in addition?

For a front end pagination, it would be good to see the count of the collection at all, and the count of the filtered collection if a filter or search is present. Something like

```
Showing 10 of 27 records (filtered from 530 records)
```

10 would be the result from `$top` (i.e. the actual payload of the response json's `value`), 27 would be the filtered/searched result amount, and 530 would be the original collection's count.

Is there anything besides $count which would enable that, or what is $count actually about?

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of these query options are defined in http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-os-part1-protocol.html.

You can plan with them on http://services.odata.org/v4/OData/OData.svc, for example:
[http://services.odata.org/v4/OData/OData.svc/Products?$count=true&$top=2&$orderby=ID%20desc&$filter=ID%20lt%208](http://services.odata.org/v4/OData/OData.svc/Products?%24count=true&%24top=2&%24orderby=ID%20desc&%24filter=ID%20lt%208) results in:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/OData.svc/$metadata#Products",
    "@odata.count": 8,
    "value": [
        {
            "ID": 7,
            "Name": "DVD Player",
            "Description": "1080P Upconversion DVD Player",
            "ReleaseDate": "2006-11-15T00:00:00Z",
            "DiscontinuedDate": null,
            "Rating": 5,
            "Price": 35.88
        },
        {
            "ID": 6,
            "Name": "Pink Lemonade",
            "Description": "36 Ounce Cans (Pack of 3)",
            "ReleaseDate": "2006-11-05T00:00:00Z",
            "DiscontinuedDate": null,
            "Rating": 3,
            "Price": 18.8
        }
    ]
}
```

But it seems that $skip doesn't work.

Comment: I still don't see whether there is a difference between the complete collection amount, the filtered results amount and the amount from the pagination...?

At the example shown, there is the explicit amount "8" and the implicit amount 2 (which is the count of the value[] items).
So in that case, what does 8 refer to? Collection amount or $filter amount?

Comment: ok sorry, I tricked myself: looks like the 'count' refers to the amount regardless of $top and $skip, but with considering $filter.